# TypeScript: Mixin for implementation of abstract class

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a mixin for the implementation of an abstract class implementation

So I have an abstract class

```js
abstract class A {
    doStuff(): void {
        this.doMoreStuff();
    }

    abstract doMoreStuff(): void;
}
```

and an implementation for which I want a mixin:

```js
class B extends A {
    doMoreStuff(): void {
        console.log(3 + 5);
    }
}
```

This mixin, for example, does some additional reporting when work is done:

```js
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: unknown[]) => T;

function WorkReporter<T extends A, TBase extends Constructor<T>>(Base: TBase): TBase {
    return class W extends Base {
        doStuff(): void {
            console.log("Does stuff");
            super.doStuff();
        }

        doMoreStuff(): void {
            console.log("Does more stuff!");
            super.doMoreStuff();
        }
    };
}
```

And eventually, the mixin is used:

```js
const ReportedWork = WorkReporter(B);
new ReportedWork().doStuff();
```

---

However, I can't get this to work.
I can't find a way how to create a mixin not for A itself, but for any implementation of A.
For the mixin, I get:

```
Class 'W' incorrectly extends base class 'T'.
  'W' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'A'.
```

And for the doMoreStuff call within the mixin, I get:

```
Abstract method 'doMoreStuff' in class 'A' cannot be accessed via super expression.
```

How can I achieve this? I need a mixin which calls the implementation of an abstract super class and extending its functionality.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
super.doMoreStuff();
```

try

```
(Base.prototype as A).doMoreStuff?.call(this);
```

and why not just

```
function WorkReporter<TBase extends Constructor<A>>(Base: TBase): TBase { ...
```

Comment: "and why not just": because I want to avoid exactly that. I don't want the Base to maybe have `doMoreStuff` and having runtime checking. I want TypeScript to enforce during type checking to have an implementation passed instead. that's why I started to play around with the type of the mixin and extended it beyond the normal `TBase extends Ctor<A>`